# Bootstrap contianer half normal half fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has two types of containers: responsive fixed width container and full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport. I need to build an container which left side if fixed width and right side is full width. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible. Then you have to download codes and edit them as what you want.

Comment: It's Possible. What you've tried so far? show us a bootply.com example.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/NdX0RNFCQx I don't know if this is right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is not designed for this type of layout since columns widths are percentage-based (fluid). You'd need to override ride columns widths and media queries. For example..

```
#fixed {
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    padding-top:5px;
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  #fixed {
      width: inherit;
      min-width: 585px;
      max-width: 585px;
      background-color:#f5f5f5;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      position:relative;
      overflow: auto;
  }
  #fluid {
      width:calc(100% - 585px);
  }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/sCawdD3m0D

Answer (score 0):

depends on your needs. I had the same problem, i wanted a container on the left and a fluid image on the right half

i fixed it for me using a normal container and a 50% background image like here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dL2u6co7/

```
.background{
  height:500px;
  background-image : url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-1.jpg);
  background-position: 100% 0;
  background-size:50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

and hided the image on mobile